# Non-intrusive design of generic C++ class

Tags: c++, templates

Using C++ 14, templates and a Bridge pattern, I'm trying to create a generic way of adding objects to a container named Shapes (vector of Shape objects). I would like to be able to automatically support new datatypes which are added to the container and print them without modifying the original implementation of the Shape class. Instead, I would like to only provide a new print(T) function, and everything should work out-of-the-box.

Below is my code, I still have some problems getting it to compile. Can anyone please help me out? Many thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print(const int toPrint) {
    cout << " " << toPrint;
    cout << endl;
}

void print(const double toPrint) {
    cout << " " << toPrint;
    cout << endl;
}

void print(const vector<int> & toPrint) {
    for (auto & it : toPrint) {
        cout << " " << it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print(const map<int, string> & toPrint) {
    for (auto & it : toPrint) {
        cout << "     " << it.first << " : " << it.second << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

class Shape {
public:
    template<typename T>
    Shape(T &&t) {
        pimpl_ = make_unique<Specialization<T>>(t);
    }
    void print() const {
        pimpl_->print();
    }
private:
    struct Base {
        virtual void print() const = 0;
        virtual ~Base() = default;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Specialization: public Base {
        Specialization(T &t) :
                internalObject_ { std::move(t) } {
        }
        void print() const override {
            ::print(internalObject_);
        }

        T internalObject_;
    };

    unique_ptr<Base> pimpl_; 

};

typedef vector<Shape> Shapes;

void print(Shapes const & shapes) {
    for (auto & shape : shapes) {
        shape.print();
    }
}

int main() {
    Shapes shapes;

    shapes.push_back(1);
    shapes.push_back(2.0);
    shapes.push_back(0.3);

    shapes.push_back(vector<int> { 10, 11, 12 });
    shapes.push_back(map<int, string> { { 0, "elmo" }, { 1, "leom" } });

    print(shapes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question...

Comment: This is going to be a challenge to answer. The code above has many issues. The biggest of them all is probably that you're trying to write what's essentially library code - what you call "generic". That's pretty hard. And you seem to be missing the basics - there's a `new` in the code there, and a violation of the rule of three. You mention C++14, but this isn't even good C++98. At this point, you should probably be reading intermediate-level C++ books.

Comment: If you need a type-generic wrapper you can use `boost::variant` or `std::variant` in C++ 17.

Comment: MSalters, actually a violation of the rule of 5 in C++14. Thanks for the info, I didn't use a smart pointer to keep it simple. This code is for learning purposes only.

Comment: `internalObject_ = new T(t);` that should be `: internalObject_{std::move(t)}`

Comment: And please, **please** use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @MSalters, Guillaume better now? I am open to constructive criticisim. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: At this point, I'm going to point at the first comment - what's the question now? (Code reviews have their own SE site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a patched up version of your code which compiles (on clang). As pointed out in the comments **there are several issues that need to be addressed** (this code leaks memory for example), but this should get you back on track.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print(int toPrint) {
    cout << " " << toPrint;
    cout << endl;
}

void print(double toPrint) {
    cout << " " << toPrint;
    cout << endl;
}

void print(vector<int> toPrint) {
    for (auto & it : toPrint) {
        cout << " " << it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

class Shape {
public:
    template<typename T>
    Shape(T t) {
        pimpl_ = new Specialization<T>(t);
    }
    void print() const{
        pimpl_->print();
    }
private:
    struct Base {
        virtual void print() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Specialization: public Base {
        Specialization(T t) {
            internalObject_ = new T(t);
        }
        void print() const{
            ::print(*internalObject_);
        }

        T* internalObject_;
    };

    Base * pimpl_;
};

typedef vector<Shape> Shapes;

void print(Shapes const & shapes) {
    for (auto & shape : shapes) {
        shape.print();
    }
}

int main() {
    Shapes shapes;

    shapes.push_back(1);
    shapes.push_back(2.0);
    shapes.push_back(0.3);

    shapes.push_back(vector<int> { 10, 11, 12 });
    print(shapes);
    return 0;
}
```